# How can I setup automatic Git pull to Ubuntu server from Push to Bitbucket

Tags: php, git, ubuntu, deployment, hook

I'm looking for a solution like "Git hooks" but my setup is that I'm using Bitbucket as central repository and I'm trying to use webhooks with by posting to a route in Php laravel where I have tried various pull scripts like this https://github.com/antriver/auto-git-pull from github without any luck.

I'm using digital ocean droplet ubuntu server with nginx Php Laravel and have configured SSH access from server to bitbucket.

Does anyone here know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BitBucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) to SSH into your server and `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

I did it with webhook . repo -> settings ->workflow->webhooks. and did call to my server. with script for pull
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html